# tracking event for amp page with GA

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, amp-analytics

I need to track a specific custom event for **AMP pages with Google Analytics**. 
I'm using this script https://riveted.parsnip.io/ (a plugin for GA) to calculate active time on single pages of my website. 
The Event Category is "*Riveted*".

How can I do it?

With the code below, analytics identify only simple visit in real time, but I do not find the visit between the events section (behavior).
I suppose I need to add some properties to the amp-analytics code. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks ;)

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
<script type="application/json">
{ 
"vars": {
  "account": "XX-XXXXXXXX-X"
},
"triggers": { 
  "trackPageview": { "on": "visible", "request": "pageview" } 
} 
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```